# Add get current date and add 5 days on the next value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datapicker

I'm trying to create a booking button where's it should get the current date put it on "from" and would add 5 days to put it in "To" day.

so it looks something like this.

```
$(function() {
    $('#booknow').click(function() {
        fromDate = getCurrentDate(); //DD/MM/YYYY
        toDate = fromDate + 5;
        url = 'http:domain.com/' + fromDate + ToDate + 'moreParameters=1;';

        window.location = url;
        });     
    }
});
```

> BOOK NOW

I'm using jquery.datepick.min.js

How am I able to achieve this?

Edit:

hmm.. Any ideas what's wrong here: http://jsbin.com/ociweb

Comment: You could use .getDay() do get the actual day or you could also split the date into different variables and add 5 to the day variable and then concat the strings and voila you have +5

Comment: @EvilP note that `.getDay()` gives you the day of the week; `.getDate()` gives day-of-month, which is what you need to use for this.

Comment: @Pointy, thet's my probolem using .getDay().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Date instance five days after another one like this:

```
 var fiveDaysLater = new Date( existingDate.getTime() );
 fiveDaysLater.setDate(fiveDaysLater.getDate() + 5);
```

The "setter" functions on the JavaScript Date prototype know how to interpret such things such that setting the day-of-month to something like 35 correctly leaves you with a date in the following month.

*edit* — if all you want is a URL as in your question, formed with the present date and the date five days from today, then:

```
$(function() {
    $('#booknow').click(function() {
        var fromDate = new Date(), toDate = new Date();

        toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() + 5);

        alert('http:domain.com/' + fromDate + toDate + '?moreParameters=1;');
        // window.location.href = 'http:domain.com/' + fromDate + toDate + '?moreParameters=1;';

   });     
});
```

Comment: Hi Pointy, Do I need an Additional jQuery plugin for this or specific version of jQuery?

I can't seem to make it work. http://jsbin.com/ociweb

Comment: It's native JavaScript; it has nothing to do with jQuery.  I'll check your jsbin code.

Comment: @Pennf0lio look my code was not intended to be a drop-in ready-to-use solution to your problem; it's just an illustration of how you manipulate dates.  You're going to have to make it work in your own context, which I don't understand from what you've posted so far.

Comment: sorry I I did not make it clear. I'm trying to pass a date to my URL. It will then point to search page where it will utilize my query string + date.

It will analyze my current date and a 5 day gap from the current day.

Comment: Thank You, very much. 

And my apologize to everyone if I didn't make it clear.

Comment: Thanks Pointy!. I added this line to formate my date.

      var setCurDate = fromDate.getMonth()+'/'+fromDate.getDate()+'/'+fromDate.getFullYear(), setToDate = toDate.getMonth()+'/'+toDate.getDate()+'/'+toDate.getFullYear();
          
        alert('http:domain.com/' + setCurDate + setToDate + '?moreParameters=1;');

Answer (score 0):

What is the `fromDate` format?
If it is like unix timestamp so it is in seconds and you need to add not 5, but 5*24*60*60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, You should use "var" to declare local variable

```
$(function() {
    $('#booknow').click(function() {
        var cDate = new Date();
        var fromDate = cDate;
        cDate.setDay(cDate.getDay()+5);
        var toDate = cDate;
        var url = 'http:domain.com/' + fromDate + ToDate + 'moreParameters=1;';

        window.location = url;
        });     
    }
});
```

Comment: The `.getDay()` function is for day-of-week; you really need to use `.getDate()` and `.setDate()` here. Also, since you've got both "fromDate" and "toDate" referencing "cDate", they'll both end up being the same value in the URL that's built.

Comment: Hi Darek, I tried this approach but I can't seem to call the functions. Can you take a look at my code? 

http://jsbin.com/ociweb

Comment: Yoy have got ToDate instead of toDate (lowercase letter)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var today = new Date();
var numberofDays = 5;
var newDate = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()+numberofDays);
```